# How to get top-right and bottom-left coordinates of an image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have an UIImageView with image as AspectFit. I need to place two buttons, one at top-right and other at bottom-left position of image as shown in image below.

How can I get image coordinates of these position to place the buttons correctly.

Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

Comment: Try AspectFill of UIImageView

Comment: @YunCHEN have to do with AspectFit only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the image rect fitting the `UIImageView` using the `AVFoundation` framework:

```
import AVFoundation ´

let fittedRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: (image?.size)!, imageView.frame)
let height = fittedRect.height
let width = fittedRect.width
```

Then use it to calculate button position (depending on which view you're adding the button to).

Comment: Use the `originPoint.y + imageHeight` and `originPoint.x + width`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it could solve your problem  but i have put that two button just like this.

**Step 1:**

Did Autolayout in imageView.Fixed Width and height and center aligned(It's your wish to be aligned)
[image]

**Step 2:**

And aligned those two buttons with respect to this imageView.

1.Trailing

2.Vertical Spacing

3.Fixed width and height

[image]

This way those buttons are now aligned with image.

**Portrait**

[image]

**Landscape**

[image]